# My comment (from two year old question) just got deleted now, Why or Why now?

Tags: discussion

some time ago a recently registered user have asked a question on Server Fault ([how to block mailto in firefox running on windows 10 - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/774633/how-to-block-mailto-in-firefox-running-on-windows-10/774820)), 
which involved Firefox browser running on Windows 10 (screenshot attached)

[image: before]

I left commented `superuser.com` as IMHO question it is Off-Topic and I did attempted to answer question anyways...

Yet Michael Hampton replied to my comment saying "This is perfectly on topic here".

I'm looking at this question now and all of the sudden my (and Michael) comment are gone and I didn't delete it.

[image: after]

Please advise.

Answer (score 10):

Why now? I just noticed them again today, after someone flagged the post again for an unrelated reason.

Why are they deleted? I deleted them. Remember that [comments are temporary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/189912); when they're no longer relevant or useful they may be deleted.

Obviously none of us have time to delete every obsolete or useless comment, but we generally will when we see them.